# RMagick lost color quality when resize and composite

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, jpeg, rmagick

I'm trying to use RMagick to apply a texture in image. Basically I need to put a image in pillow placeholder.

When execute the resize the original image and the necessary composite operations, the color quality is reduced drastically.

Take a look in a original image: 
[image]

When execute the composite:
[image]

My doubt is: Why the colors change?

Here is my code:

```
 design = Magick::Image.read(file_path).first
 design.resize_to_fit!(1000,1000)
 3.times do
    base_layer.composite!(
      design,
      (1600 - design.columns) / 2,
      (1067 - design.rows) / 2,
      Magick::OverCompositeOp
    )
  end
```

Can someone help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the OverCompositeOp is the problem. Try AtopCompositeOp.

[Here's the ImageMagick doc](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose_operators) about the composite operators.

I'm not sure why you're doing the composition 3 times. Once should be enough.